# Multiple OnClickListeners in Fragment with CustomAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-arrayadapter

**Problem:** I am trying to implement three different `OnClickListeners` via floating action buttons into every item of a recycler view. Each of the three FABs does something different so they need different `OnClickListeners`. I think I am able to instantiate one with my current adapter setup, but I would like to be able to access all three in the fragment via something like this:

```
   mRecyclerView2.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration2);
   mLayoutManager2 = new GridLayoutManager(mContext, 3);
   mRecyclerView2.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager2);
   mAdapter2 = new photo_adapter2(mContext, arrayList2);
   mRecyclerView2.setAdapter(mAdapter2);

   mAdapter2.floatingActionButtonDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 int position = mRecyclerView2.getChildAdapterPosition(v);
                 photo_item2 item = mAdapter2.getDataSet().get(position);
                 final String key = item.getMatchId();
            }
        });


   mAdapter2.floatingActionButtonView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int position = mRecyclerView2.getChildAdapterPosition(v);
                photo_item2 item = mAdapter2.getDataSet().get(position);
                final String key = item.getMatchId();
            }
        });


   mAdapter2.floatingActionButtonChat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int position = mRecyclerView2.getChildAdapterPosition(v);
                photo_item2 item = mAdapter2.getDataSet().get(position);
                final String key = item.getMatchId();
            }
        });
```

I get the following error when I move to the fragment:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.firetest.Tabs.MatchProcess.MatchFragment.onCreateView
```

**Adapter:**

```
public class photo_adapter2 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<photo_adapter2.ViewHolder> {

    ImageView imageView;
    FloatingActionButton floatingActionButtonDelete;
    FloatingActionButton floatingActionButtonChat;
    FloatingActionButton floatingActionButtonView;

    private Uri imageUri;
    private ArrayList<photo_item2> mDataSet;
    private Context mContext;
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;
    
    public ArrayList<photo_item2> getDataSet() {
        return mDataSet;
    }
    public void setDataSet(ArrayList<photo_item2> mDataSet) {
        this.mDataSet = mDataSet;
    }
    public ImageView getImageView() {
        return imageView;
    }
    public void setImageView(ImageView imageView) {
        this.imageView = imageView;
    }
    public Context getContext() {
        return mContext;
    }
    public void setContext(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }
    public Uri getImageUri() {
        return imageUri;
    }
    public void setImageUri(Uri imageUri) {
        this.imageUri = imageUri;
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public photo_adapter2(Context context, ArrayList<photo_item2> DataSet) {
        mDataSet = DataSet;
        mContext = context;
    }

    public ArrayList<photo_item2> DataSet() {
        return mDataSet;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView mImageView;
        public FloatingActionButton floatingActionButtonDelete;
        public FloatingActionButton floatingActionButtonView;
        public FloatingActionButton floatingActionButtonChat;
        public RelativeLayout mLinearLayout;
        private int adapterPositionOnCLick;

        public ViewHolder(View v, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
            super(v);

            mImageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv);

            floatingActionButtonDelete = (FloatingActionButton) v.findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButtonDelete);
            floatingActionButtonChat = (FloatingActionButton) v.findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButtonChat);
            floatingActionButtonView = (FloatingActionButton) v.findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButtonView);

            floatingActionButtonDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (listener != null) {
                        adapterPositionOnCLick = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (adapterPositionOnCLick != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) ;
                        listener.onItemClick(adapterPositionOnCLick);
                    }
                }
            });
            floatingActionButtonChat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (listener != null) {
                        adapterPositionOnCLick = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (adapterPositionOnCLick != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) ;
                        listener.onItemClick(adapterPositionOnCLick);
                    }
                }
            });

            floatingActionButtonView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (listener != null) {
                        adapterPositionOnCLick = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (adapterPositionOnCLick != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) ;
                        listener.onItemClick(adapterPositionOnCLick);
                    }
                }
            });
            mLinearLayout = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.ll);
        }
        public ImageView getImageView() {
            return mImageView;
        }
        public void setImageView(ImageView mImageView) {
            this.mImageView = mImageView;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public photo_adapter2.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.photo_custom_view_card, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v, (OnItemClickListener) mListener);
        return vh;

    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final photo_item2 photo_item = mDataSet.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataSet.size();
    }
}
```

How would I go about creating three `onClickListeners` like this? How should I modify my current fragment and adapter set up to achieve that? Please let me know if there is anything else I should add to my post.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you can create an `interface` `onFabClickListener` to dispatch the original `onClick` event on the `FloatingActionButton` to your `Activity` or `Fragment`. If three `FloatingActionButtons` are only way to interact with the **row** of `RecyclerView`, then I guess you don't even need to handle `onItemClick()`(or one which handle onclick of row overall).

The interface `onFabClickListener.java` may look like this :

```
// is supposed to handle every fab click of every viewholder
public interface OnFabClickListener {
    // view to know which fab was click and position to know the position
    // of viewholder that was clicked
    void onFabClick(View view, int position);
}
```

Then your `Adapter` class may look like this :

```
public class photo_adapter2 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<photo_adapter2.ViewHolder> {

// you all other variable declarations
private ArrayList<photo_item2> mDataSet;
private Context mContext;
private OnFabClickListener mListener;

// your all other required methods definition

public void setOnFabClickListener(OnFabClickListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}

public ArrayList<photo_item2> getDataSet() {
    return mDataSet;
}

public void setDataSet(ArrayList<photo_item2> mDataSet) {
    this.mDataSet = mDataSet;
}

public photo_adapter2(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public photo_adapter2.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.photo_custom_view_card, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v, mListener);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final photo_item2 photo_item = mDataSet.get(position);
    // do you stuff here
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataSet.size();
}


public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    private OnFabClickListener listener;

    public ViewHolder(View v, final OnFabClickListener listener) {
        super(v);
        // your all other view initialization

        //setting our listener object
        this.listener = listener;

        // your all other views declaration
        FloatingActionButton floatingActionButtonDelete = v.findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButtonDelete);
        FloatingActionButton floatingActionButtonChat = v.findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButtonChat);
        FloatingActionButton floatingActionButtonView = v.findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButtonView);

        // setting onclicklisteners on them
        // our view holder class is gonna handle all of the onclick
        floatingActionButtonDelete.setOnClickListener(this);
        floatingActionButtonChat.setOnClickListener(this);
        floatingActionButtonView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // if the view is a floating action button and listener is not equal to null
        if (view instanceof FloatingActionButton && listener != null) {
            if (getAdapterPosition() != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                // for every on click listened here we will dispatch it to our activity or fragment which
                // is required to respond to those events
                listener.onFabClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
            }
        }
    }

    // your all other methods definition
}
}
```

Then now a sample `MainActivity` which implements our custom `onFabClickListener` will receive the appropriate onclick events handled and dispatched initially by our `photo_adapter2` class may look like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnFabClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // declare and initialize the recyclerview
    RecyclerView rcView = ......
    // declare and initialize the requiredadapter
    photo_adapter2 adapter = .....
    // set the data using setDataSet() or you can skip this if you
    // already passed the dataset in the constructor
    adapter.setDataSet(yourDataSet);
    // set this class as the onFabClickListener(you forgot this one I guess)
    adapter.setOnFabClickListener(this);
    // set the adapter to the recyclerview
    rcView.setAdapter(adapter);
}


@Override
public void onFabClick(View view, int position) {
    int id = view.getId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.floatingActionButtonDelete:
            // you can now do your stuff here
            break;
        case R.id.floatingActionButtonChat:
            // for eg get the item associated with the viewholder of whose fab was clicked
            photo_item2 item = mAdapter2.getDataSet().get(position);
            break;
        case R.id.floatingActionButtonView:
            break;
    }
}
}
```

---

**Note:**
According to Material Design Specifications, it is not recommended to use more than one `FloatingActionButton` in the single screen(`Activity`/`Fragment`). It represents the most important single frequent action that is performed by the user. Instead, I think you should switch to `MaterialButton` and if you are using `Fab` just to get this circular look, you need to switch immediately. You can specify the `materialButtonStyle` attribute in your `styles.xml` file to get a circular look.

Comment: I think this is going to work. I had to implement a few other things before I could test this. With this coded in, the clicks are not being registered in the fragment but a Log.d() does post in the adapter onClick prior to the two if statements. Maybe this has to do with the fact that I added the data to the adapter using mAdapterMatch = new photo_adapter_match(mContext, arrayListMatch); instead of setDataSet() ? I would prefer to not use setDataSet();

Comment: Removal of the two ifs gives me the error: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void.OnFabClickListener.onFabClick(android.view.View, int)' on a null object reference.

Comment: From your `MainActivity` / `Fragment`, you need to set the instance of `onFabClickListener` object using `setOnFabClickListener()` of `photo_adapter2` class. You can write something like `yourAdapterObj.setOnFabClickListener(this);`

Comment: Or check my edited answer. Sorry that I didn't properly write the code for `MainActivity/Fragment` which is responsible to handle the dispatched event orginally handled inside adapter.

Comment: I apologize for not seeing that before. I'm still a beginner so I miss things. Anyways, this worked! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Check your XML file where all three floating action buttons are created, make sure you have them all created, with the respective names that you accessing from the view. The NullPointerException is telling you that one of your floating action button's are pointed to something that doesn't yet exist.